# Efficient way to find all the possible combinations given definite choices for each index of result?

Tags: c#, algorithm, combinations

Say I have this list:

```
[0] {1, D}
[1] {3}
[2] {A, 5}
[3] {8, 1, C}
```

and I want to generate all the possible combinations using the elements in the list in the index position. The total number of combinations given the list would be 2 x 1 x 2 x 3 = 12.

```
Example:
possible1: 13A8
possible2: 13A1
possible3: 13AC
possible4: D3A8
```

and so, on. There is a definite set for the index of the combination. I tried searching the internet but I don't know what to search for -__-. I'm currently coding in C# but a pseudocode will do. Thanks in advance, stackoverflow community!

Comment: Thanks! I'll read it.

Comment: The question linked is C#-specific, you can also search for n-ary cartesian product, as this seems what the question is about on the language-agnostic level.

Comment: This is what I'm looking for. I remember the term now: cartesian product. I smiled at "language-agnostic". Thanks Rafal Dowgird.